# AWK how to initialize a variable with multiple number of fields to print

Tags: shell, awk, field

I'm writing a SHELL script that will call an AWK script file printing specific fields based on the options specified by the user from the .sh script

```
EXAMPLE

-N=field with a list of Names               ==> is the field number 2
-A=field with a list of Addresses           ==> is the field number 4
-P=field with a list of Prices              ==> is the field number 6
-D=field with a list of Dates               ==> is the field number 10


./SHELLSCRIPT.sh -N -A -P -D

NAMES,ADDRESSES,PRICES,DATES
NAMES,ADDRESSES,PRICES,DATES
NAMES,ADDRESSES,PRICES,DATES
```

EXAMPLE

```
./SHELLSCRIPT.sh -N -D

NAMES,DATES
NAMES,DATES
NAMES,DATES
```

I'm trying to initialize a variable inside AWK using the -v option passing the number of fields but I'm having some difficulties on printing it...

here is the AWK script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
        FS="\",\"" ;
        -v test=2,4,6,10
        for (i in test)
        print $test[i];
        }
```

AWK script must exclude some field/s when the user doesn't specify some option/s in the shell script.

Comment: +1 for showing sample input and sample output, -1 for not including  your code ;-)... If you know about `-v` for awk, you can't be too far away from a working solution. Add your code and we can help you, other wise you're expecting us to play 20 questions with you. Good luck.

Comment: If you are passing more than one variable into awk, oddly enough, you must specify `-v` before each and every one - caught me out before now!!!

Comment: or you can `split(test,inArr, ","); for(i in inArr) ...` Good luck to all.

Comment: Thanks shellter, the "split" function is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

`-v` is an awk ARGUMENT, not a language construct. It's something you specify on the awk command line, like `-F`. Nevere use a shebang to invoke awk from a script as it just takes away from available functionality. Instead of what you had:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {...}
```

you'd do this:

```
/usr/bin/awk '
BEGIN {...}
' "$@"
```

which then lets you use awk args, access shell positional parameters, exported variables, etc. as you like, e.g.:

```
/usr/bin/awk -v test='2,4,6,10' '
BEGIN {...}
' "$@"
```

Now, to address your actual problem you'd write:

```
/usr/bin/awk -F'"," -v test='2,4,6,10' '
BEGIN {
    split(test,array1,/,/)
    for (i in array1)
        array2[array1[i]]
}
{
    print "array1:"
    for (i=1; i in array1; i++) {
        print i, $(array1[i])
    }
    print "array2:"
    for (i in array2) {
        print i, $i
    }
}
' "$@"
```

array1 would be what you use when you do care about the order in which the fields are output, array2 would be when you don't care about the order.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this wil help:

```
awk -v bozo=12 -v brains=99 'BEGIN{print bozo,brains}' /dev/null
12 99
```